# Using Jest with HTTPS and SSL

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jest

I am using Jest version 0.1.6 to handle the requests to and from an AWS Elastic Search cluster (ver 1.5). It seems that Jest defaults to HTTP, however I see in the latest versions of Jest you can enable HTTPS through:

```
JestClientFactory factory = new JestClientFactory();
factory.setHttpClientConfig(new HttpClientConfig.Builder("https://localhost:9200")
                .defaultSchemeForDiscoveredNodes("https").build();
```

However that doesn't appear to be available in Jest 0.1.6. Is there any way to use HTTPS in the earlier versions of Jest?